# How to use template literal on a function paremeter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to concatenate a string to shape an object, like this:

```
{addInput.inputs.map((input, index) => (
  <FormField
    key={input}
    label="Entreprenuer Name*"
    controlId={`entreprenuerName-${index}`}
    onChange={e => {
      startupFourthStepFormActionHandler({ `entreprenuerName-${index}`: e.target.value });
    }}
    value={startupFourthStepForm.entreprenuerName}
  />
))}
```

But I am getting a `Failed To Compiled` error and `Property assignment expected` on this line:

```
onChange={e => {
      startupFourthStepFormActionHandler({ `entreprenuerName-${index}`: e.target.value })
};
```

All I want is to add the `index` to the `entreprenuerName-` key on the object.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computed object keys need to be wrapped in `[]`. Try this:

```
  startupFourthStepFormActionHandler({ [`entreprenuerName-${index}`]: e.target.value });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) inside brackets `[...]` for what you are trying to do. This is the way to use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), example:

```js
let index = 1;

const obj = {
   [`entreprenuerName-${index}`]: "some_value"
};

index = 2;
obj[`entreprenuerName-${index}`] = "some_other_value";

console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Or, in your particular case, change the code to this:

```
{addInput.inputs.map((input, index) => (
    <FormField
        key={input}
        label="Entreprenuer Name*"
        controlId={`entreprenuerName-${index}`}
        onChange={e => {
            startupFourthStepFormActionHandler({
                [`entreprenuerName-${index}`]: e.target.value
            });
        }}
        value={startupFourthStepForm.entreprenuerName}
    />
))}
```